# How to encrypt the KeyIdentifier for a WSSecDKEncrypt derived key?

Tags: java, xml, ws-security, wss4j

I'm encrypting a Document in java using WSSecDKEncrypt with the following setup:

```
// Load the key information to create a derived key
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(FILESTORE_PATH_CONST), KEY_PASSWORD_CONST.toCharArray());
byte[] keyBytes = clientStore.getKey(KEY_NAME_CONST, KEY_PASSWORD.toCharArray()).getEncoded();

WSSecDKEncrypt encBuilder = new WSSecDKEncrypt();
encBuilder.setSymmetricEncAlgorithm(WSConstants.AES_256);
encBuilder.setDerivedKeyLength(24);
encBuilder.setExternalKey(keyBytes, KEY_NAME_CONST);
encBuilder.setKeyIdentifierType(3);
```

In my output the derived key looks like this:

```
<wsc:DerivedKeyToken wsu:Id="DK-13">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-5F19CCE1DE10D253ED15220696801308">
           <wsse:Reference URI="#KEY_NAME_CONST" />
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        <wsc:Offset>0</wsc:Offset>
        <wsc:Length>24</wsc:Length>
        <wsc:Nonce>SN2DMIkt7GjFe5pjqxFKgw==</wsc:Nonce>
</wsc:DerivedKeyToken>
```

I would like the KeyIdentifier to be an encrypted reference, similar to the format I have in an example message that I'm trying to emulate:

```
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0">
            <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKeySHA1">IGEEUhgV2G/ojXFCrKVNWjzcwxQ=</o:KeyIdentifier>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
            <c:Length>24</c:Length>
            <c:Nonce>8p3Un1ciYQfTw8vSLpYtiA==</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
```

I'm using an older version of WSS4j, 1.6.9, the latest that works with Java 1.7.

Comment: Only references are supported at the moment.

Comment: Ah damn, that's not great. Do you know if there is anything I could use to encrypt the key and manually insert that as a reference?